# Start Activity from Dialog when having kiosk mode enabled

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

I have this android app that needs to start an activity to reload a theme, the code below works fine if the app is not in its kiosk mode (lock state). But in kiosk mode this code doesn't seem to do anything. Any guesses why? I am running this from a AlertDialog.

```
 val intent = Intent(rootView.applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
            rootView.finish()
            rootView.applicationContext.startActivity(intent)
```